Any way to place a dialog over a modal dialog?
I have a dropdown control which is implemented a dialog (seems a div would behave the same), any way to place it over a modal dialog so it would behave as a dropdown and be independent of the modal? Tried several things with z-index, no luck:


modal.showModal();
.dialog,
.popup {
  z-index: 100000;
  position: absolute;
}

#modal {
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 90px;
}

.popup {
  top: 70px;
  background: #faa;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

dialog,
.popup {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
<dialog open class="dialog">Dialog</dialog>
<div class="popup">Popup</div>
<dialog id="modal">Modal
  <dialog open class="dialog">Dialog</dialog>
  <div class="popup">Popup</div>
</dialog>




Hm, I misunderstood. Dropdowns on the actual popup seems trivial... you must have an issue too difficult to reproduce on a Snippet. I just found this: Popover API which allows you to use any content element as a dialog, good luck, sir. Btw, that answer should really be a comment.

Thanks for the answers, I've just decided to open the modal full page size and use it as a top layer window where I show the actual dialog like container and every other dropdowns added to it (not to the body) will behave as i need

There's two ways to open a <dialog>:

With the .showModal() method the <dialog> behaves as a modal. A modal will block the rest of the page from user interaction so a dropdown would definitely be inaccessible while a modal is open.

Or with the .show() method which makes it behave as a dialog. A dialog does not interfere with user interaction with the page so a dropdown is definitely accessible while a dialog is open.


If you want the <dialog> to be open when the page loads, use the methods instead of the [open] attribute  because you'll have more control and more options. In the example below, there two <button>s that open a <dialog> both ways. There's also a dropdown to test both modes with. Details are commented in the example.


// Reference <dialog>
const popup = document.getElementById("popup");

// Reference the first <form>
const bg = document.forms.btnGrp;
// Reference all <button>s in first <form>
const io = bg.elements;

// Reference the second <form>
const df = document.forms.dmForm;
// Reference all <button>s, <fieldset>s, and <output> in second <form>
const oi = df.elements;
// Reference <output>
const msg = oi.message;

// Bind first <form> to the "submit" event in order to prevent redirect
bg.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault();

/**
 * Bind #modBtn to the "click" event. When event is triggered:
 *   - the .showModal() method open #popup as a modal
 *   - #message will display blue text
 *   - #modBtn and #dlgBtn will be disabled
 */
io.modBtn.onclick = e => {
  popup.showModal();
  msg.value = `This is a modal not a dialog.`;
  io.dlgBtn.toggleAttribute("disabled");
  e.target.toggleAttribute("disabled");
}

/**
 * Bind #dlgBtn to the "click" event. When event is triggered:
 *   - the .show() method open #popup as a dialog
 *   - #message will display blue text
 *   - #modBtn and #dlgBtn will be disabled
 */
io.dlgBtn.onclick = e => {
  popup.show();
  msg.value = `This is a dialog not a modal.`;
  io.modBtn.toggleAttribute("disabled");
  e.target.toggleAttribute("disabled");
}

/**
 * Bind #popup to the "close" event. When #popup closes #dlgBtn and #modBtn
 * will be re-enabled
 */
popup.onclose = e => {
  io.modBtn.toggleAttribute("disabled");
  io.dlgBtn.toggleAttribute("disabled");
}
:root {
  font: 4vmin/1.1 "Segoe UI"
}

body {
  background: #bbb;
}

main {
  position: relative;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.25rem;
  border-bottom: 3px outset grey;
}

#dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: -0.25rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
}

summary {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.navLnx {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#btnGrp {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.2rem;
  right: 0;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 0;
}

#dmForm {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer
}

#popup {
  max-width: 70vw;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

#popup::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0 0 0 / 50%);
}

fieldset {
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}

legend {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  transform: translateY(1.25rem);
}

#message {
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: blue;
}

#popup ul {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
<main>
  <header>
    <details id="dropdown">
      <summary>Dropdown</summary>
      <nav>
        <menu class="navLnx">
          <li><a href="/">0</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">6</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">7</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">8</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">9</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">A</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">B</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">C</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">D</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">E</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">F</a></li>
        </menu>
      </nav>
    </details>
    <form id="btnGrp">
      <button id="modBtn">Modal</button>
      <button id="dlgBtn">Dialog</button>
    </form>
  </header>

  <dialog id="popup">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Modal or Dialog?</legend>
      <p>
        <output id="message" form="dmForm"></output>
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>A modal takes priority and focus from everything else on the page. Normal interaction is blocked with the exception being the modal of course.</li>
        <li>A dialog doesn't monopolize the user's attention and interaction with the page is possible whilst the dialog is open.</li>
      </ul>
      <p>The OP probably wants the latter.</p>
      <form id="dmForm" method="dialog">
        <button>OK</button>
      </form>
    </fieldset>
  </dialog>
</main>




There is no problem about open a modal hover an open one...


modal1.showModal();

modal2.showModal();
#modal1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

#modal1::backdrop {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
}

#modal2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#modal2::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.4);
}
<dialog id="modal1">modal 1 use escape</dialog>
<dialog id="modal2">modal 2 use escape</dialog>



